# Get Date Range Of financial Year in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

How can I get the Financial Year date range in PHP like below when I pass year and return date range of every year start and end.

Like Eg.

```
Input Array = [2017,2018]
Financial Start Month = 04
```

Output Array =

```
[
    '2017' => [
            'start' => '2016-04-01',
            'end' => '2017-03-31'
     ],
    '2018' => [
            'start' => '2017-04-01',
            'end' => '2018-03-31'
     ]
]
```

My Effort:-

```
$year_arr = [2017,2018];

$fn_month = 04;

$date_range_arr = [];

foreach ($year_arr as $key => $value) {

  $fn_start_date_year = ($value - 1);

  $fn_start_date_month = $fn_month;

  $fn_start_date_day = '01';

  $fn_start_date_string = $fn_start_date_year.'-'.$fn_start_date_month.'-'.$fn_start_date_day;

  $start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fn_start_date_string));


  $fn_end_date_year = ($value);

  $fn_end_date_month = (fn_month == 1)?12:(fn_month-1);

  $fn_end_date_day = date('t',strtotime($fn_end_date_year.'-'.$fn_end_date_month.'-01'));

  $fn_start_date_string = $fn_end_date_year.'-'.$fn_end_date_month.'-'.$fn_end_date_day;

  $end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fn_start_date_string));

  $date_range_arr[$value] = [
    'start_date' => $start_date,
    'end_date' => $end_date
  ];
}
```

Above is my effort. It is working perfectly but needs a more robust code.

Comment: Can you show us your efforts?

Comment: You can get // First day of the month.
`echo date('Y-m-01', strtotime($query_date));`

// Last day of the month.
`echo date('Y-m-t', strtotime($query_date));`
To get first and last day. Rest I expect you can work around

Comment: Please check my effort now if you can help us then it will be great.

Comment: @DhawalBhavsar Check robust and optimized answer you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to manipulate dates in PHP is using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. Here's an example of how to get the results you want using it. By using the [`modify`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method, we can avoid worries about complications like leap years (see the result for 2016 below).

```
$year_arr = [2016,2017,2018];
$fn_month = 03;

foreach ($year_arr as $year) {
    $end_date = new DateTime($year . '-' . $fn_month . '-01');
    $start_date = clone $end_date;
    $start_date->modify('-1 year');
    $end_date->modify('-1 day');
    $date_range_arr[$year] = array('start_date' => $start_date->format('Y-m-d'), 
                                   'end_date' => $end_date->format('Y-m-d'));
}
print_r($date_range_arr);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [2016] => Array ( 
        [start_date] => 2015-03-01 
        [end_date] => 2016-02-29
        )
    [2017] => Array ( 
        [start_date] => 2016-03-01 
        [end_date] => 2017-02-28 
        )
    [2018] => Array ( 
        [start_date] => 2017-03-01 
        [end_date] => 2018-02-28 
        )
    )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/KUnPN)

Comment: Leap years is not a problem for strtotime either. And as a added bonus strtotime is faster and uses less memory. So what is it that makes DateTime "the best option"?

Comment: @Andreas I wasn't trying to imply that leap years were a problem for `strtotime`. I personally prefer an OOP approach, but that is personal so I've changed my wording and removed "best".

Comment: Nick Thanks man for helping your function is too good and it's dynamically working. i really appreciate Nick.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need?

I use strtotime to parse the date strings.

```
$year_arr = [2017,2018];
$fn_month = 04;
$date_range_arr = [];

foreach($year_arr as $year){
    $date_range_arr[$year] =['start' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year-1 . "-" .$fn_month . "-01")),
                             'end' =>  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year . "-" .$fn_month . "-01 - 1 day"))];
}

var_dump($date_range_arr);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [2017]=>
  array(2) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2016-04-01"
    ["end"]=>
    string(10) "2017-03-31"
  }
  [2018]=>
  array(2) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2017-04-01"
    ["end"]=>
    string(10) "2018-03-31"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/nMUHt

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet,

```
function pr($a)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}
$year_arr = [2017, 2018];
$fn_month = 4;
$date_range_arr = [];
foreach ($year_arr as $key => $value) {
    $fn_month = str_pad(intval($fn_month),2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    $date = "".($value-1)."-$fn_month-01"; // first day of month
    $date_range_arr[$value] = [
        'start_date' => $date,
        'end_date'   => date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date.' 11 months')), // last month minus and last date of month
    ];
}
pr($date_range_arr);
die;
```

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) - Pad a string to a certain length with another string

Here is working [demo](http://tpcg.io/9UJMNI).